# I can not get MEAN JS to create new customer

Tags: javascript, node.js, meanjs

I am new to Node JS and MAEN stack , i am following a tutorial to MEANJS to learn it and in this screencast http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HNpMCFB8TFI&list=PL6rhBJX0L3TWYrwrQIi1_MzQDvVhkUVPI&index=26 we get to create new customer . However, i am not able create a new customer as i am getting an error message says "object is not a function" which refers to this line "var customer = new Customers" as the console in google chrome suggests . here is the code

```
customersApp.controller('CustomersCreateController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Customers',
    function($scope, Customers ) {
            // Create new Customer
            this.create = function() {
                    // Create new Customer object
                    var customer = new Customers ({
                            firstName: this.firstName,
                            surname: this.surname,
                            suburb: this.suburb,
                            country: this.country,
                            industry: this.industry,
                            email: this.email,
                            referred: this.referred,
                            phone: this.phone,
                            channel: this.channel
                    });

                    // Redirect after save
                    customer.$save(function(response) {
                            // Clear form fields
                            $scope.firstName = '';
                            $scope.surname = '';
                            $scope.suburb = '';
                            $scope.country = '';
                            $scope.industry = '';
                            $scope.email = '';
                            $scope.referred = '';
                            $scope.phone = '';
                            $scope.channel = '';

                    }, function(errorResponse) {
                            $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
                    });
            };
    }
```

]);

kindly , note that the update function in the update controller works fine , here is the code .

```
customersApp.controller('CustomersUpdateController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Customers',
function($scope, Customers ) {
    // Update existing Customer
    this.update = function(updatedCustomer) {
        var customer = updatedCustomer;

        customer.$update(function() {
        //wont do anything as the modal will be closed
        }, function(errorResponse) {
            $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
        });
    };
}
```

]);

i really would appreciate your help , thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your dependencies list, you are passing in $stateParams, $location, and Authentication, which may not be needed.

```
CustomersApp.controller('CustomersCreateController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Customers',
    function($scope, Customers ) {
```

Regardless, the order you specify in the dependencies array is the order that they will be passed into your controller. So, in your controller, "$scope" refers to *$scope*, but "Customers" refers to *$stateParams*.

You can probably change it to look like this:

```
CustomersApp.controller('CustomersCreateController', ['$scope', 'Customers',
    function($scope, Customers ) {
```

Or, if you need those services:

```
CustomersApp.controller('CustomersCreateController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Customers',
    function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Customers ) {
```

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a controller in angular you pass in 2 parameters: the name of the controller and an array that contains all of the names of other variables and modules that the controller requires and finally the constructor method of the controller at the end of the array.

Now the method signature of the constructor method needs to line up with the array of parameters passed in through the array.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');
myApp.controllers('myController', ['$scope', 'foo', 'bar', // note the position for these
  function($scope, foo, bar) {                             // match the position of these
    foo.doStuff(bar);
  }
]);
```

So in your example you can see that you're mapping the parameters incorrectly

```
customersApp.controller('CustomersCreateController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Customers',
  function($scope, Customers ) { // note the arrangement of these parameters
```

If you map the arrangement of the parameters in the function to what's declare in the array you'll see that the `Customers` object is actually mapped to the `$stateParams` object and you're calling that as a function.

If you arrange your required parameters to match the method signature of the constructor then your example should start to work (assuming that the other code is wired up correctly)

```
customersApp.controller('CustomersCreateController', ['$scope', 'Customers', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', // note that we moved 'Customers' to be next to '$scope'
  function($scope, Customers ) {
```

The reason your other example works is that you're not actually using the `Customers` module anywhere in the code.

It also doesn't seem like you're using any of those other required variables and modules in these controller and if that is the case then you should remove those as well.

Now as to why angular does this? That's because when you put a JavaScript file through a minimizer tool it's very common for these tools to rename the passed in parameters of a function to reduce the over all size of a file.

E.g.
`function(foo, bar) { /* code */ }`

will become
`function(a, b) { /* code */ }`

Thus, this provides a way for angular to maintain a way to declare dependencies through modules and not have them removed via a minimizer.